# How to define a matrix product based on a different scalar product

Tags: functions, matrix, function-construction

I want to define a product of 3x3 Matrices where the coefficient behave in a different way as usual. I defined the multiplication between coefficient as the function MyScalProd

```
MyScalProd[x_, y_] := (x^2*y + y^2*x)/2; (*scalar product*)
```

and now I want to use it to multiply coefficients involved in the matrix product. I tried as I could this way

```
ProdMat[z_, a_, b_] := (
  z = Array[cc, {3, 3}];
  cc[1, 1] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[1, 1]], b[[1, 1]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[1, 2]], b[[2, 1]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[1, 3]], b[[3, 1]]];
  cc[1, 2] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[1, 1]], b[[1, 2]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[1, 2]], b[[2, 2]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[1, 3]], b[[3, 2]]];
  cc[1, 3] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[1, 1]], b[[1, 3]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[1, 2]], b[[2, 3]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[1, 3]], b[[3, 3]]];
  cc[2, 1] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[2, 1]], b[[1, 1]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[2, 2]], b[[2, 1]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[2, 3]], b[[3, 1]]];
  cc[2, 2] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[2, 1]], b[[1, 2]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[2, 2]], b[[2, 2]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[2, 3]], b[[3, 2]]];
  cc[2, 3] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[2, 1]], b[[1, 3]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[2, 2]], b[[2, 3]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[2, 3]], b[[3, 3]]];
  cc[3, 1] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[3, 1]], b[[1, 1]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[3, 2]], b[[2, 1]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[3, 3]], b[[3, 1]]];
  cc[3, 2] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[3, 1]], b[[1, 2]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[3, 2]], b[[2, 2]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[3, 3]], b[[3, 2]]];
  cc[3, 3] = 
   MyScalProd[a[[3, 1]], b[[1, 3]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[3, 2]], b[[2, 3]]] + 
    MyScalProd[a[[3, 3]], b[[3, 3]]];
  )(*MatrixProduct based on MyScalProd*)
```

1. I would like to have a function so that given two matrices I can write "Z=ProdMat[A,B]"
2. the above code seem to work only the first time I call the procedure, while the second time gives problems involving the reuse of the old variables.
   Let me know if you have solutions

Comment: While off-hand I see several issues, it is important to ask: what is the syntax with which you call this function, such that you have success on the first call, but subsequent calls result in errors, as you mentioned?

Comment: Is something like ProdMat[A1, X, Y]; ProdMat[A2, Y, X] ... the result is something like this https://gyazo.com/b571084a443d77c4b1eacdd417f5e5bb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this works only once is that

- you define the matrix `z` symbolically in terms of the symbols `c[i,j]`
- then you define the symbols `c[i,j]`.
- but the symbol `c` is not scoped.

When you call `ProdMat` the second time then `c[i,j]` is already defined; so `z = Array[cc, {3, 3}];` writes directly to the variable `z`. This is why later changes to `c` cannot affect `z`.

Also you use `z` as input variable. Mathematica does not allow to modify the inputs unless `ProdMat` has one of the attributes `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll`.

A short and more flexible approach would be something like

```
ProdMat[a_, b_] := Table[ 
  Sum[MyScalProd[a[[i, k]], b[[k, j]]],{k,1,Dimensions[a][[2]]}]
  ,{i,1,Dimensions[a][[1]]}
  ,{j,1,Dimensions[b][[2]]}
  ]
```

A repaired version of your original code look like this:

```
ProdMatRepaired[a_, b_] := Module[{z},
  z = ConstantArray[0, {Dimensions[a][[1]], Dimensions[b][[2]]}];
  Do[
   z[[i, j]] = Sum[
     MyScalProd[a[[i, k]], b[[k, j]]]
     , {k, 1, Dimensions[a][[2]]}
     ]
   , {i, 1, Dimensions[a][[1]]}, {j, 1, Dimensions[b][[2]]}];
  z
  ]
```

Note how I used `Module` to scope the variable `z` and how I set the return value of the function to `z` by placing `z` at the end of the `Module` without a semicolon.

Now you can do

```
a = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 3}];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 3}];
res1 = ProdMat[a, b]; 
res2 = ProdMatFixed[a, b];
```

Both lead to the same result:

```
res1 == res2
```

> True

Comment: just to be sure I understood the problem: if I had put "z = Array[cc, {3, 3}];" after the definition of the symbols c[i,j] it would have worked?

Comment: Yes, it would. But it would have been more robust (and probably more efficent) to create an empty matrix `z = ConstantArra[0,{3,3}]` and then write `z[[i,j]] = ...` instead of `cc[2, 3] = ...`.

Comment: and so I would have to write in the syntax: ProdMat[A,B]; res=z; t have the result stored in  matrix "res"?

Comment: No. I would return `z` as the result of `ProdMat` so that one can simply write `res = ProdMat[A,B]`. Like I did in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand... but it would be very helpful for me. Could you please rewrite in your answer the fix you would have done to the original code? Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much! Superhelpful!

Answer (score 5):

The function `Inner` allows you to define an inner product, where you can specify the functions for multiplication and addition.
So you can define for example a new operator

```
CircleDot[x_List,y_List]:=Inner[MyScalProd,x,y,Plus];
CircleDot[x_List,y_List,z__]:=CircleDot[CircleDot[x,y],z];
```

which leads the same result as the implementation of Henrik Schumacher

```
a ⊙ b === ProdMat[a,b]
(* True *)

b ⊙ a ⊙ b
(* {{4799469, 4613164, 4067140}, {824411, 803114, 681023}, {3772584,  4714759, 1968481}} *)
```

Comment: This is a neat implementation. I don't follow why matrix multiplication is an inner product though?

Comment: @Joe Yes you are right, it's not an inner product for matrices. What I really meant is that ```Inner``` is a generalization of ```Dot```, which acts an inner product for vectors.